# How to set button image condition in Swift 3

Tags: uibutton, swift3, xcode8

I have these **3 (three) UIButton** with **two images (active.png and notactive.png)**

```
Official
Personal 1
Personal 2
```

My goal is when I select one of the button, the image is set to active.png while the other two button is set into notactive.png

And the selected button is **store in UILabel output**

Appreciate if someone can help.

**button.swift**

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
// MARK: Outlets

@IBOutlet var officialButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var personal1button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var personal2button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var outputLbl: UITextField!

// MARK: Properties

var output: String!
var buttons: [UIButton] {
    return [officialButton, personal1button, personal2button]
}

// MARK: Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    buttons.forEach {
        $0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTouchUpInside(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        $0.setImage(UIImage(named: "notactive"), for: .normal)
        $0.setImage(UIImage(named: "active"), for: .selected)
    }
}

// MARK: Methods

func didTouchUpInside(button: UIButton) {

    buttons.forEach { $0.isSelected = false }
    button.isSelected = !button.isSelected

    outputLbl.text = nil

    if button.isSelected {
        outputLbl.text = button.currentTitle
    }
    else if officialButton.isSelected {
        outputLbl.text = "Official"
    }
    else if personal1Button.isSelected {
        outputLbl.text = "P1"
    }
    else if personal2Button.isSelected {
        outputLbl.text = "P2"
    }
}
```

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet var officialButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var personal1button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var personal2button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var outputLbl: UITextField!

    // MARK: Properties

    var output: String!
    var buttons: [UIButton] {
        return [officialButton, personal1button, personal2button]
    }

    // MARK: Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        buttons.forEach {
            $0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTouchUpInside(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            $0.setImage(UIImage(named: "notactive"), for: .normal)
            $0.setImage(UIImage(named: "active"), for: .selected)
        }
    }

    // MARK: Methods

    func didTouchUpInside(button: UIButton) {

        buttons.forEach { $0.isSelected = false }
        button.isSelected = !button.isSelected

        outputLbl.text = nil

        if button.isSelected {
            outputLbl.text = button.currentTitle
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it first . I let you know if its work

Comment: it gives an error on "buttons.forEach { $0.isSelected = false }"

Comment: $0 is stand for ? i'm not understand that part

Comment: Radio button seems to work fine, but I want to display "Offcial" for officialButton, "Personal1" for personal1Button and "Personal2" for personal2Button on output.text label

Comment: on which line should i add those code ? inside didload or inside func didTouchUpInside ?

Comment: It should have been `var buttons: [UIButton]` and the `$0` is a shorthand way of getting the first argument of a closure.

Just copy and paste the `didTouchUpInside` function from my answer

Comment: Yup. already did . but outputlabel still does not display the text. and i can't see where the "Offical", "Personal1" and "Personal2" is set based on the button selected

Comment: At the bottom of the `didTouchUpInsideButton`, we set the output label to the current title of the button that was pressed if `isSelected`. I updated my answer earlier, you may not have seen the changes yet.

Comment: No, you don't need to check all the button's `isSelected`. The output label is clear every time a button is pressed. Then if the button that was pressed is selected, we set the output label's text to the currentTitle of the button.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var officialButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var personal1button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var personal2button: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var outputLbl: UITextField!

    var output: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         officialButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
         personal1button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
         personal2button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside
    }

func pressButton(button: UIButton) {
        officialButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "notactive"), for: .selected)
        personal1button.setImage(UIImage(named: "notactive"), for: .selected)
        personal2button.setImage(UIImage(named: "notactive"), for: .selected)
       button.setImage(UIImage(named: "active"), for: .selected)
       outputLbl.text = button.titlelable
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback . I'll try it first :)

Comment: somehow the image does not change when i clicked one of the button . i'm not sure why

Comment: try it with for .Normal on the place of .selected